# Mac OS X-like and gestures in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, touchpad, multi-touch

Anyone knows of a solution which exists in order to have Mac OS X like gestures in Ubuntu?

Something extremely close to this is being developed for the next version of Elementary OS:

https://blog.elementary.io/multitouch-gestures-in-elementary-os-6/

I believe this solution is closely tangled to Pantheon desktop environment which makes me think that additional work will have to be done in order to have have it perform with Gnome, e.g. smooth windows spread like this, but in Gnome:

[image]

Any idea if similar solutions are available or being developed for Ubuntu & Gnome?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Touchégg](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg) is being developed to do that. I haven't tried it out so I can't speak to how well it does, but it does seem to be in active development.

Comment: I'm aware of that. But I'm looking for a solution that it is easy to install and configure, I wouldn't invest more than half an hour into configuring it to my needs.